# How to use string parameters in an URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, url

I'm using Rest api, so I send a Request with URLs, my problem is when the user nome a folder with a name containing a space or special characters, it sends nothing. I used the following conversion, but it does not work:

```
string url = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/set/folder/permission/?folderName="
             + folder
             + "&permi="
             + acces
             + "&username="
             + user
             + "&alf_ticket="
             + GetToken();

Uri url2 = new Uri(url);
Response.Write(url2);
```

Comment: Try to encode the value using `Server.UrlEncode(user)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to URL encode the variables in order to make them safe. Use [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string urlSafeFolder = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(folder);
```

Use that variable in your URL and you will be fine. (You will have to do this for every parameter you pass in!)

Comment: it's work, thank you, this function remplace space by +, but my request don't work, my url is in this way 
<url>/set/folder/permission/?folderName={folderName}&amp;permi={permi?}&amp;username={username?}&amp;alfTicket={ticket?}</url>

Comment: Your comment is unclear. What the problem exactly? Maybe it is better to ask a new question with a clear problem statement and reproduction scenario.

Answer (score 0):

When ever any user types in space or any special character in the url we need to encode it using UrlEncode method --

```
string urlSafeFolder = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(folder);
```

So if a space is present inside url it will be converted to %20 and so on.
For complete reference check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp